# Change filter on a video using GPUImage

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I have a problem trying to change filters.

On my viewDidLoad I do this:

```
filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];
filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[filter addTarget:filterView];
```

filterView is declarated on .h with GPUImageView *filterView;

My problem is on this method:

```
-(void)changeEffect
{
[videoCamera removeAllTargets];
[filter removeAllTargets];
filter = [[GPUImageColorInvertFilter alloc] init];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];
[filter addTarget: filterView];
}
```

On the instruction [filter addTarget: filterView] I receive this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do this before adding

```
filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
```